# What exactly is meant by research statement for postdoc application?

Tags: mathematics, application, postdocs

I am a PhD student in mathematics and have started applying for postdoctoral positions. There are, mostly, three types of requirements:

- a research statement and a research proposal,
- only a research proposal,
- only a research statement.

The first two options are clear to me: *research statement* means the research so far done, while *research proposal* means the proposed projects that I would like to work on if I am selected for the position.

But the third option is not clear to me. Because in my opinion, the research statements for the first case and 3rd cases are not equivalent.

Do I have to add both the research proposal and the previous research report together when only the research statement is required?

Comment: "research statement means the research so far done" False.

Comment: @AdamPřenosil, thanks for the input. So I guess, you are suggesting to incorporate both "previous research" and "future research plan" in the research statement.

Comment: @TheDoctor, Yes, it is a similar question; however, there are only two answers. So I think it is good to leave this question here so that more people can share their opinions.

Comment: @learner If you are applying for a research position, presumably you need to tell them somewhere what your research plans are. I suppose if they have both a "research statement" and a "research plan" (I have not encountered this situation myself), then you can split it the way you suggest (past vs. future research), but otherwise you should tell them about your research plans in whatever research statement/plan/thing they request. Edit: sorry, I might have misread, I guess you are basically saying the same thing in your OP.

Comment: @AdamPřenosil, thanks for sharing your opinion and confirming my intuition. I agree with your reasoning.

Answer (score 2):

Generally the research statement for a postdoc position should specify the topic of interest and research which will be worked on during the tenure of the position. Generally new PhDs aims to continue their previous research work as they have publications and thesis in them but it is not mandatory in any way, you can present a purely new topic but will need to show publications or other validations that you have experience in that topic to be accepted.

Comment: Thanks for your input. I agree